# Do the spins of outer orbitals block measurement of spin of inner orbitals?

Tags: electronic-configuration, periodic-trends, periodic-table, spin

Do the outermost s1 and s2 electrons block an outside observer from measuring the larger inner group orbitals for elements heavier than Nitrogen (for instance, would Chromium's 4s1 electron or Manganese's 4s2 electrons prevent you from detecting the spin of the 3d5 electrons in either case?)

I edited this into an individual question from the original list of them per moderator instruction.

Comment: Have you heard about Aufbau principle?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal The Aufbau principle doesn't seem to hold up for the description of Vanadium, Chromium, Maganese and most other elements beyond group 2 (that is, inner orbitals get partially filled then jump to filling the next group of orbitals before going back downward.)

Comment: It does hold for vanadium. Ot doesn't hold for chromium because $\mathrm{3d^5}$ is exceptionally stable due to being half filled.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Vanadium is `[Ar] 3d3 4s2` - meaning the `4s` subshell gets filled before the `3d` subshell.

Comment: Well yeah? 4s does come before 3d in the Aufbau series. [Look](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Scheme_of_Madelung_Rule.jpg/220px-Scheme_of_Madelung_Rule.jpg) here.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Ah, I think I'm following it now.  I was reading it backwards thinking that `3d` was getting filled out to `3d3` then `4s` was getting filled to `4s2` but judging by Potassium and Calcium this is wrong.  This does still come back to the original question I had though, would the outer suborbitals block the inner suborbitals?  That is, would the `4s2` in Vanadium prevent you from distinguishing between all-up or all-down `3d3` suborbitals in different atoms?  Same question for things like Manganese with `3d5`.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your first question, as you get to higher energy levels, the distance between each one increases and as a consequence the shells get closer together and begin to overlap. This is also seen with 5s and 4d iirc.